# to_string(index = False) results in non empty string even when dataframe is empty

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am doing the following in my python script and I want to hide the index column when I print the dataframe. So I used .to_string(index = False) and then use len() to see if its zero or not. However, when i do to_string(), if the dataframe is empty the len() doesn't return zero. If i print the procinject1 it says "Empty DataFrame". Any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
procinject1=dfmalfind[dfmalfind["Hexdump"].str.contains("MZ") == True].to_string(index = False)
if len(procinject1) == 0:
    print(Fore.GREEN + "[✓]No MZ header detected in malfind preview output")
else:
    print(Fore.RED + "[!]MZ header detected within malfind preview (Process Injection indicator)")
    print(procinject1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour in Pandas DataFrame.

In your case, `procinject1` stores the string representation of the dataframe, which is non-empty even if the corresponding dataframe is empty.

For example, check the below code snippet, where I create an empty dataframe `df` and check it's string representation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
print(df.to_string(index = False)) 
print(df.to_string(index = True))
```

For both `index = False` and `index = True` cases, the output will be  the same, which is given below (and that is the expected behaviour). So your corresponding `len()` will always return non-zero.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

But if you use a non-empty dataframe, then the outputs for `index = False` and `index = True` cases will be different as given below:

```
data = [{'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C':30}, {'A':5, 'B': 10, 'C': 15}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_string(index = False)) 
print(df.to_string(index = True))
```

Then the outputs for `index = False` and `index = True` cases respectively will be -

```
A  B  C
10 20 30
5 10 15

    A   B   C
0  10  20  30
1   5  10  15
```

Since pandas handles empty dataframes differently, to solve your problem, you should first check whether your dataframe is empty or not, using [pandas.DataFrame.empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html).

Then if the dataframe is actually non-empty, you could print the string representation of that dataframe, while keeping `index = False` to hide the index column.